# Meteor on windows - Server crashes on code push

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I installed Meteor for windows from here :
http://win.meteor.com

The server crashes almost every time I try to make live code push.

I would then have to end the mongod.exe process and run 'meteor reset' and 'meteor' to start it up back again.

Here are the logs:

```
=> Meteor server restarted
events.js:71
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: This socket is closed.
    at Socket._write (net.js:519:19)
    at Socket.write (net.js:511:15)
    at Socket.HttpProxy.proxyWebSocketRequest.reverseProxy.incoming.socket.on.listeners.onOutgoing (C:\Program Files\Meteor\lib\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\node-http-proxy\http-proxy.js:515:35)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:397:14)
```

Anyone on the same boat? I read from here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/513 that this has been an open issue for over 6 months.

Someone's got any workaround? Help appreciated.

Comment: this is so annoying... can't believe they don't have official windows support yet. I always delete the `mongod.lock` in `.meteor\local\db` to start the server again. (Does not wipe the DB)

Answer (score 1):

The EADDRINUSE issue was fixed in 0.6.3.1-rev4, but please update to version 0.6.4 as this problem seems to have resolved the other issue by the update to the http-proxy package.

For MSI downloads see https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor/wiki/Windows

Should also appear on http://win.meteor.com soon

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with windows for meteor : https://github.com/sdarnell/meteor/issues/7. The one on meteor's github repo might also be related. I have it too! Hopefully they sort it out soon!. Just ctrl+c to stop your server before you edit code and get it back up after you're done.

Even if you start it after this sometimes you could also get an ADDRINUSE error, which is quite frustrating.